# How to join multple coulmns in one table with the other table in laravel

Tags: laravel

| business_id | supported_by | reccomended_by | approved_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 312 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

| staff_id | name | address | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx | yyy | 158931478 |
| 2 | aaa | lll | 158958936 |
| 3 | ccc | 12wee | 154531478 |

I want to join supported_by,reccomended_by, and approved_by columns in the first table with the staff_id of the second table and want to "select" their names. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

[# Advanced Join Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses)

```php
$staffs = DB::table('businesses')
    ->select('staffs.name')
    ->join('staffs', function ($join) {
        $join->on('businesses.supported_by', '=', 'staffs.staff_id')
            ->orOn('businesses.reccomended_by', '=', 'staffs.staff_id')
            ->orOn('businesses.approved_by', '=', 'staffs.staff_id');
    })
    ->where('businesses.business_id', '=', 312)
    ->get();
```

```
foreach ($staffs as $staff) {
    $staff->name
}
```